# Postman multiple customer accounts and credentials

Tags: postman

I am using Postman in my customer API integrations support.

I have a collection containing different API endpoints at DHL and I have multiple customers that integrate to this same endpoints for which currently I duplicate the collections and assign API credentials in the Collection -> Authorization settings tab.

But this duplication is troublesome cause then I work with a customer and make changes to the collection, changes that don't propagate to the other duplicated collections and I though maybe by using only 1 collection and multiple environemnts, 1 environment = 1 customer with their API credentials stored, then I have all progress and work from duplicated collections in one place.

Is this the way to go, or do you think there's a better way of doing it?

Currently I have 20 APIs from various companies and 20+ customers, and it's hard to maintain all duplicate collections.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible at the moment. There's an open issue about it: [Reuse the same request inside several collections #1535](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1535)

I had asked a very similar question at the postman community forum. Some workarounds have been proposed: [How to implement DRY / good coding practices?](https://community.postman.com/t/how-to-implement-dry-good-coding-practices/5500)